# Store temp file in .net lambda and then publish to s3Bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am generating a .csv file for further storing in a s3 bucket using .net c# Lambda function.

This is the process i follow:

1. Generate the .csv and store it in /tmp/ folder of the lambda function execution.
   In this step im not sure if it is really saving the file in that path.

   ```
       //filepath = @"/tmp/test.csv"
       try
       {
           using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@filepath, true))
           {

               file.WriteLine(ID + "," + workItemType + "," + title + "," + assignedTo + "," + state + "," + iterationPath);                    
               Console.WriteLine("Successfully added");
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw new ApplicationException(" somethings wrong: ", ex);
       }
   ```
2. Upload the file to s3 bucket.

   ```
       try
       {
           await client.PutObjectAsync(new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest
           {
               BucketName = "mys3bucket",
               Key = "test.csv",
               ContentType = @"/tmp/test.csv"
           });
       await Task.CompletedTask;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Exception in PutS3Object:" + ex.Message);                ;
       }
   ```

In this last step i get this error message:

> Exception in PutS3Object:The format of value '\tmp\test.csv' is invalid.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your error does not match your code. Error says `tetest.csv`, code uses `test.csv`. Why is that?

Comment: Typo there, sorry.

Comment: by the way, that typo was because i copiedf my code to this question, my error still persist.

Comment: Try ContentType = @"text/csv"

Comment: It works! it get published to s3 bucket, but it comes empty,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the **data** to include in the csv file:

```
    await client.PutObjectAsync(new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = "mys3bucket",
        Key = "test.csv",
        ContentBody = DATAINSTRINGFORMAT,
        ContentType = @"text/csv"
    });
```

or as **filepath** to send:

```
    await client.PutObjectAsync(new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = "mys3bucket",
        Key = "test.csv",
        FilePath = FILEPATHONYOURTEMPFOLDER,
        ContentType = @"text/csv"
    });
```

Comment: FilePath  was missing! thanks

Comment: you also can use a stream, but as you're asking to send a file...